# numpy float64 1.0 is not equal to 1.0

Tags: python, numpy

I have a probability matrix, should be adding up to 1.
Then have this assertion in my code which makes no sense to me:

```
assert np.sum(space) == 1.0
```

This gives me an assertion error. When I add these lines:

```
print np.sum(space)
print np.sum(space).__class__
print np.sum(space) == 1.0
print int(np.sum(space)) == 1
```

This gives me:

```
1.0
<type 'numpy.float64'>
False
False
```

Why is this numpy float not equal to 1.0? This makes absolutely no sense to me. When I put this in the plain python terminal:

```
np.float64(1) == 1.0
```

This gives me:

```
True
```

WTF?

Comment: There is likely some float precision error can you try `np.isclose(np.sum(space), 1.0)`